# trouble installing isce2 in Colab: "cudatoolkit=12.2 is missing from the target environment"

Tags: conda, google-colaboratory, conda-forge, feature-tracking

I run the fallowing instructions, but it dosen't work!

```bash
!nvcc --version
**nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_15_22:02:13_PDT_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.2, V12.2.140
Build cuda_12.2.r12.2/compiler.33191640_0**
```

```bash
!conda install -c conda-forge isce2
**Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - cudatoolkit=12.2**
```

I tried installing with `conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf202003" isce2` but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

### Conda Forge not yet building `cudatoolkit=12.2`

This is reported in [this `condacolab` Issue](https://github.com/conda-incubator/condacolab/issues/60). Essentially, the presence of CUDA v12.2 triggers Conda (or `condacolab`?) to inject a pin of `cudatoolkit 12.2.*`, but Conda Forge isn't yet building `cudatoolkit=12.2`. This renders any mutating operation with Conda/Mamba broken for now. Eventually, this will be fixed (follow [the Issue](https://github.com/conda-incubator/condacolab/issues/60)).

### Workaround

In the meantime, one can simply remove the pinning with:

```bash
!sed -i '/cudatoolkit/d' /usr/local/conda-meta/pinned
```

and then Conda should function normally.

[Here's a demo notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1m1lz-xePpf_gD-R-tUDGlIOFFk3d_AuV?usp=sharing) where I install `isce2` and check the version after loading in Python.